# using subversion (svn) on linux

Tags: linux, svn

I'm trying to install svn on my linux (raspberry pi) computer.
What I've done:

Installed Subversion

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Created a directory to hold the repositories

```
mkdir -p /home/pi/repos
```

But when I try to create new repository with command like this:

```
svnadmin create /home/pi/repos/<repo name>
```

I got error:

```
-bash: svnadmin: command not found
```

I understand that it is environment error - os cannot find command svnadmin, but how to write path to svnadmin file? Unfortunately I have little experience with linux systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian systems `svnadmin` is usually installed in `/usr/bin`, so try this:

```
/usr/bin/svnadmin
```

Or you can find it with:

```
dpkg -L subversion | grep svnadmin
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention.
It seems that I didn't install subversion from first try :-). After repeating sudo apt-get install subversion all works perfect